# VML internet explorer versions

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, charts, vml

i am reading some things about VML, but i have some doubts.

What versions of Internet explorer support VML? The IE9 have full support to SVG?

now VML is deprecated? correct?

so, for example the dojo charting is showed in ie 7/8 not as svg but as VML?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VML was Microsoft's version of SVG. It's available in IE5 - IE9 (though [deprecated as of IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384217(v=vs.85).aspx) and [not supported in IE10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801223(v=vs.85).aspx)). IE9+ support SVG, mainly because the rest of the world was moving on with SVG and no one had interest in supporting VML.

I'm not familiar with Dojo Charting, but it could be using VML. I looked at the Demo in IE9 and it was using elements like `roundrect`, which is part of VML.

Comment: They do not continue to develop it (improve on it), but they continue to support it (keep it in the browser). In fact, they haven't done any development on it since 1998. Microsoft will be favoring SVG going forward.

Comment: Do you know any article with this information? I am really interested in this subject

Answer (score 1):

SVG has for a long time been an international standard for Vector Graphics and is now supported as part of HTML5
  - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_svg.htm

VML has been supported since IE5 and SVG since IE9.

I've developed apps in VML in the past - but been very disappointed that MS did not support the industry standard SVG.

I've recently developed a new C# app that uses an IE browser component to view large diagrams rendered as SVG, VML or PNG bitmaps. If IE9 is available it makes use of SVG, otherwise VML. The SVG implementation in IE9 is *hardware accelerated* and so renders *much* faster. One of my large diagrams typically takes over 100 seconds to render in VML and under 1.5 second in SVG!

All the other major browsers support SVG as part of their initiates to migrate to HTML5.  In addition, Microsoft will soon include IE9 (and it successors) as a standard part of Windows Update meaning most Windows computers will have SVG support. So basically VML is now dead (at last!) and we can finally move forward with a single universal industry standard for browser based vector markup along with the other rich HTML5 markup suite.

Comment: what about the embedded internet explorer mobile(5, v), can it handle vml?